# Why Vert.x codegen fails to create rx-fied classes?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx4

For some reason my 4.0.2 based code doesn't produce rx-fied service versions with codegen.

Both VertxEBProxy and VertxProxyHandler classes are created as expected though.

Here is a demo project: https://github.com/ashertarno/playground

Please see the required dependencies below:

```
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-core:$vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-rx-java2:$vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion"
implementation "io.vertx:vertx-rx-java2-gen:$vertxVersion"

annotationProcessor "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion:processor"
annotationProcessor "io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion"
```

What would be missing in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `io.vertx:vertx-rx-java2-gen:$vertxVersion` as an `annotationProcessor` and `testAnnotationProcessor`. After I did that, I had the classes get generated:

```
./build/classes/java/main/me/tarno/playground/reactivex/BaseServiceProxy.class
./build/classes/java/test/me/tarno/playground/reactivex/TestProxy.class
```

Comment: nice catch. actually i tried this, but now i see that i stupidly copy pasted : processor to it, that's why it didn't work.